# No funciona animación JavaScript al filtrar por clase

Tags: javascript, html5, filtros-css

Tengo el típico **"portafolio"** en que tengo unos botones que quiero que filtren el contenido por clase.

El filtro funciona, pero no consigo que quede animado. Ahora mismo, cuando un elemento desaparece el elemento que contiene el filtro se queda en su lugar y después se mueve a la izquierda bruscamente. Quisiera que se desplazara de manera fluida mientras los elementos que no contienen el filtro seleccionado desaparecen.

Estoy usando *Bootstrap 4*, no sé si tendrá algo que ver, si algún *script* o clase estarán interfiriendo o hay algo que me pueda faltar agregar.

He estado buscando y probando, pero **no tengo mucho conocimiento en JavaScript** y no he conseguido solucionarlo.

Les dejo el código por si alguien puede ayudar.

Fragmento HTML:

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 text-center mb-5">
  <button class="btn btn-borde m-3 filter-button active" data-filter="all">Todos</button>

  <button class="btn btn-borde m-3 filter-button" data-filter="QH7">QH7</button>
  <button class="btn btn-borde m-3 filter-button" data-filter="QH5">QH5</button>
  <button class="btn btn-borde m-3 filter-button" data-filter="QH5U">QH5 U</button>
  <button class="btn btn-borde m-3 filter-button" data-filter="QH2">QH2</button>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3  filter QH7"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 filter QH5"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 filter QH5U"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3 filter QH2"></div>
```

Fragmento JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".filter-button").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).attr("data-filter");

    if (value == "all") {
      //$('.filter').removeClass('hidden');
      $(".filter").show();
    } else {
      // $('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').removeClass('hidden');
      // $(".filter").not('.filter[filter-item="'+value+'"]').addClass('hidden');
      $(".filter")
        .not("." + value)
        .hide();
      $(".filter")
        .filter("." + value)
        .show();
    }
  });

  if ($(".filter-button").removeClass("active")) {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  }

  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Hola Josep. Las animaciones se definen en el CSS, por lo que deberías buscar ahí la causa del problema. Puedes consultar la referencia de MDN [Usando animaciones CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: Hola Sokkian, gracias por la respuesta. He tratado de hacer las animaciones en CSS pero no he conseguido que se anime. Seguramente no estaré poniendo bien la el "class" y por eso no funciona. Hasta donde llegué, no tengo manera de animarlo.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el CSS involucrado en las animaciones.

Comment: Hola Triby, no tengo CSS definido ya que aunque lo haga sigue sin animarse.